# fullcalendar scheduler vertical-resource-view recurring background appointments

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I'm using fullcalendar scheduler plug in (with mvc 5 app) and in the example [vertical-resource-view](https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-scheduler-1.4.0/demos/vertical-resource-view.html) I want to do something similar by adding a set of recurring background events at specific times.  For example 10:15am for one hour then 2pm for one hour.   Clicking one on of these events will show a modal to actually create a booking.

How can I  show the recurring background events so that the only clickable area on the calendar are the events themselves?

Comment: what have you tried so far? Creating a background event is similar to creating any other event except that you specifiy `rendering: "background"` in the event's properties. Have you tried something and encountered a problem? From your question it's unclear exactly what difficulty you're facing.

Comment: Thanks.  I have updated the question yo make it a bit clearer

Comment: Are you really wanting to have only certain times when a user can click to create events? To achieve that you might be better off with businessHours (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/business-hours) and/or selectConstraint (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selectConstraint)